# Get Hour and Minute from timestamp in Java

Tags: java, timestamp

I try to extract the hours + minute from the timestamp below. I tried this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = sdf.parse("2016-03-23 18:08:59");

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String dateStr = sdf2.format(date);
```

But I get an "unhandled exception: Java.text.parseException" in this line:

> Date date = sdf.parse(myTimeStampString);

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What is the value of the variable myTimeStampString?

Comment: @user1917363 its already in the question

Comment: It is something like I mentioned in the first line of my question.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine for me,

Comment: what is IST? is it india, israel or ireland?

Comment: ok. I see that. I was looking at the code. Didn't realize it.

Comment: Why are you converting timezone, and which timezone do you want? `IST` is not universally unique.

Comment: Why not use a `java.util.Calendar` to extract the hours and minutes after you've parsed the date?

Comment: @progNewbie And what is 'something like' what you mentioned in the first line of your question? It is obviosly not the same string, since that would work and not throw an exception.

Comment: In my machine it also works as well. Where do you get a timestamp from? I remember myself facing similar issue when timestamp arrived with some unprinted characters

Comment: If you get a parseException, then your `myTimeStampString` does not contain a value like `"2016-03-23 18:08:59"`. Check your assumptions.

Comment: @jarnbjo In fact I also tried exactly this string and got the same error message. I wrote "something like" becaue I generate this timestamps dynamically.

Comment: Print out a few of your generated timestamps and include them in the question, it might help.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I get it from my server send through tcp/ip to my app :-D But if I print it out in Android using Log.d I get the String from my question.

Comment: When typing this line: Date date = sdf.parse("2016-03-23 18:08:59"); I get the error as well.

Comment: See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/W6sVJa) for working version of your exact code, with the exact value you displayed. *Unable to reproduce!!!*

Comment: @progNewbie yes, that was exactly the issue in my case. Try to print this string char-by-char to see if unprinted characters exist. Or even byte-by-byte so see if `'-'` and `' '` are correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant this will be but what version of java/ide are you using?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou As I mentioned (and now edited the question) it also doesn't work if I hardcode the timestamp.

Comment: @Matthew Good question. I am using the Androids SDK, but it's up to date.

Comment: @progNewbie then it is very strange.

Comment: @progNewbie Are you sure that you are not referring to a compiler error and that the compiler tells you that you have to handle a potentially thrown ParseException in that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the part of the string that has `"18:08"` and you don't want to adjust according to timezone, then you could just use `String#substring(start, end)` in order to extract that part of the string.

```
String fullTime = "2016-03-23 18:08:59";
String timeStr = fullTime.substring(11, 16); //extract "HH:mm" from "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

If you *DO* want to adjust according to timezone, then add a `try` block.

```
String fullTime = "2016-03-23 18:08:59";
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
           df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
df1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
String timeStr = "";
try {
    timeStr = df2.format(df1.parse(fullTime)); //parse throws ParseException
} catch (ParseException e) { /* handle this */ }
```

This code takes the variable at the top as input in order to change `timeStr` to the value at `"HH:mm"` after adjusting the timezone.

Comment: I considered this, but I thought it would be bad style or/and unsafe.

Comment: It's not unsafe if you got the date string from a date object or from some safe place that isn't user input. You should put comments in the code though that describe exactly what it is doing.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it shows how you could do it without `substring` and adapt your code.

Answer (score 3):

Although not clear from how you phrase your question, the only reasonable explanation is that the exception is not thrown, but you refer to a compiler error.

ParseException is a checked exception and must be handled by your source code, otherwise it will not compile. I am not sure which compiler you are using, the Java compiler from Oracle's JDK gives a more detailed error description:

> error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared
>   to be thrown

Comment: Ah, that explains why their code wasn't working, because yeah, it's already working fine. It just needs to be put in a try block.

Comment: However, the time is still getting converted to 12-hour time. To fix that, they just need to change `HH` to `kk` so that the input is formatted as 24-hour time instead.

Comment: @4castle Not sure what you mean. The question was about the ParseException and not about any issues with 12/24 hour differences. Both HH and kk patterns are 24-hour based, HH formatting the hour as 0-23 and kk as 1-24.